# PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput()

Tags: postgresql, heroku

After resetting my database on my staged environment in heroku, I'm running into an error when I try to sign in as a user and this is what I see in the logs:

```
2014-07-03T17:46:14.333490+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-03T17:46:43.526093+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/log_in" host=grassrootsdotorg-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=20fe43fb-dbea-4053-a700-e07b8ab959b2 fwd="206.71.250.50" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=97ms status=500 bytes=1530
2014-07-03T17:46:43.435294+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/log_in" for 206.71.250.50 at 2014-07-03 17:46:43 +0000
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501174+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501177+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501181+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501179+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501195+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501197+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501198+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501200+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501202+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-03T17:46:43.501829+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms
2014-07-03T17:46:43.450693+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-07-03T17:46:43.450733+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"snvbSML68Nk294Gvt5GsHFtxfeVXWGkQinxi5eDwThI=", "email"=>"alice@huggey_bear.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525095+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525106+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525112+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525114+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525109+00:00 app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2014-07-03T17:46:43.499690+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525103+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525108+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525116+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525117+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525119+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525121+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-03T17:46:43.525111+00:00 app[web.1]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
```

Has anyone come across this error? I Do not know what to do. It appears that pg cannot connect with my app or it's performing a query that breaks...In my asset folder I have default avatar images for users when they have not uploaded their images. Would calling those be a problem?